# Get clicked element in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent

I'm using the following code to get the selected text, my question is, how can I get the element where the text was selected? I have 100 rows and 10 columns and I want to get the td and tr object and I want to check weather the text was selected inside the table.

```
function getSelectedText() {
  var t = '';
  if(window.getSelection){
    t = window.getSelection();
  }else if(document.getSelection){
    t = document.getSelection();
  }else if(document.selection){
    t = document.selection.createRange().text;
  }
  return t;
}
$(document).bind("mouseup", putSelectedToInput);

function putSelectedToInput(){
  var st = getSelectedText();

  if(st!=''){
    $("#params_oldname").val($.trim(st));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of binding `mouseUp` for document bind it for `td` elements,

```
$('td').mouseUp(function(){
 var selectedTd=$(this);
});
```

Comment: Jquery's .mouseUp is deprecated. Use .click instead.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check [`event.target`](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/). Be aware that if you have one or more child elements in each table cell, you need to walk up the DOM tree from `event.target` until you reach a `td` element (or not, in which case the click was outside a cell).

Answer (score 2):

You can get the clicked element in the mouseup event by doing this:

```
function putSelectedToInput(event){ // notice the event parameter

    var $clickedElement = $(event.target);
```

The clicked element may be any element inside the td. You can get the td itself with this:

```
// returns the closest parent that is a td (or the element itself if it's a td)
var $theTd = $clickedElement.closest('td');
```

See [event.target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) and [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest)

Answer (score 1):

Simply use:

```
document.onclick=function(){
elem = window.event.srcElement
}
```

Now the td or tr element which was clicked in is stored in the global variable called elem.
Note that this would return every element in which the user has clicked, so you would have to check if it was a td or tr element, like so:

```
if(elem.tagName.toLowerCase() == "td" || elem.tagName.toLowerCase() == "tr")
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this help ?

http://api.jquery.com/get/